# How to get complete file path from typo3 custom extension?

Tags: typo3

I am developing custom typo3 extension, i have include file browse option (using kickstarter ) in my plug-ins. I stores only filename. How do i find the complete path of the file?

Generally, typo3 text,text/image elements uploads files into uploads/ directory. How can i do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could also retrieve the path through the API

```
$fileName = 'foo.jpg';
$basePath = t3lib_div::getFileAbsFileName('uploads/tx_templavoila/');
$file = $basePath . $fileName;
```

However, as of TYPO3 6.0 this will become:

```
$fileName = 'foo.jpg';
$basePath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('uploads/tx_templavoila/');
$file = $basePath . $fileName;
```

Answer (score 5):

Check your `ext_emconf.php` there should be a configuration entry for creating the necessary directories like in TemplaVoila:

```
...
'createDirs' => 'uploads/tx_templavoila/',
...
```

If you need the absolute Filepath you can always use the constant `PATH_site`, e.g. check if an image exists (assuming $data is filled with the whole row and you are checking for the filename in 'image'):

```
if(is_file(PATH_site . 'uploads/tx_yourextensionname/' . $data['image'])){
    // your code here
}
```